# Changing the variable declared outside the exec function sailjs

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am pushing the values in an array declared at the beginning of the function, but at the end the array is empty.
I am printing the values after pushing and it prints them but outside the exec() the array is empty. 
I need to get all the values which I am pushing in the organizations_with_sites variable and need to send that array as a response.

```
module.exports = {getOrganizations: function (req, res) {

var userId = req.userId;
var organizations_with_sites = [];
UserPermission.find({
  where: {user: userId}
}).exec(function (err, user_organizations) {
  // users permitted organizations id
  user_organizations.forEach(function (organization, index) {
    Organization.find({
      where: {id: organization.organization}
    }).exec(function (err, organizations) {

      // users organizations
      organizations.forEach(function (organization, index) {
        Site.find({
          where: {organization: organization.id}
        }).exec(function (err, sites) {

          var organization_structure = {
            id: organization.id,
            name: organization.name,
            address: organization.address,
            sites: sites
          };

          organizations_with_sites.push(organization_structure);
        });
      });

    });
  });

});

return res.json({
  organizations: organizations_with_sites
});}};
```

Output

```
{
"organizations": []}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it's hard to get results from a `forEach` loop that uses async logic (like fetching from a database) in a the loop. You should investigate promises to handle this generally.

In your case, you can add in a hacky counter to return at the right time.

```
module.exports = {getOrganizations: function (req, res) {
  var userId = req.userId;
  var organizations_with_sites = [];
  UserPermission.find({
    where: {user: userId}
  }).exec(function (err, user_organizations) {

    // HERE track how many results you expect
    var num = user_organizations.length;

    // users permitted organizations id
    user_organizations.forEach(function (organization, index) {
      Organization.find({
        where: {id: organization.organization}
      }).exec(function (err, organizations) {

        // users organizations
        organizations.forEach(function (organization, index) {
          Site.find({
            where: {organization: organization.id}
          }).exec(function (err, sites) {

            var organization_structure = {
              id: organization.id,
              name: organization.name,
              address: organization.address,
              sites: sites
            };

            organizations_with_sites.push(organization_structure);

            // HERE return if you have all results
            if (organizations_with_sites.length >= num) {
              return res.json({organizations: organizations_with_sites});
            }

          });
        });

      });
    });

  });
}};
```